# Blender UI Manipulation Python

Tags: python

I have a couple of questions:

1. is it possible to change the color of a single button via python?(like the “add Driver” Operator does)
2. is it possible to change original blender buttons to execute something else(without changing the source .py ui file). Specifically: Then the user hits the render button, I want to trigger another function and stop the rendering.

Comment: Hi, please only ask one quesiton at a time.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8851/in-python-is-it-possible-to-change-the-background-color-of-a-property-ui

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No
2. No cleanly, you can re-define the classes from source .py ui files in your addon. Which is dirty.