# Text color of buttons and lables

Tags: python, color

Is there any way to change a text color of my own buttons or labels?
This is an example I made using image editor:

[image]

Comment: AFAIK No. Adding your own custom icon is one way to set your layout apart from the crowd.

Comment: That's a great idea, thank you! I can't accept you answer because it's a comment.

Comment: A bit late, but it is possible in some borders. At least for the label and the button hilight color.  col.active_default = True is blue. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8851/in-python-is-it-possible-to-change-the-background-color-of-a-property-ui